# A common code for iteration over two separate iterable series, and one series of pairs

Tags: c++

I have a function that calculates something from two series of numbers:

```
template<typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_non_bool_arithmetic = std::is_arithmetic_v<T> && !std::is_same_v<T,bool>;

template<typename IT, typename = std::enable_if_t<is_non_bool_arithmetic<typename std::iterator_traits<IT>::value_type>>>
double calc(IT xbegin, IT xend, IT ybegin, IT yend)
{
    while((xbegin < xend) && (ybegin < yend))
    {
        // calc something using *xbegin and *xend, keep and use some intermediate 
        // values, so it is not reasonable to call a separate function per loop pass
        ++xbegin;
        ++ybegin;
    }
    return something;
}
```

Now I'd like to implement a version that accepts range over value pairs instead of two separate series:

```
template<typename IT, template = lets_forget_about_type_checking_here>
double calc(IT xybegin, IT xyend)
{
    while(xybegin < xyend)
    {
        // calc something using std::get<0>(*xybegin) and std::get<1>(*xybegin)
        ++xybegin;
    }
    return something;
}
```

The question is: is there any generic way to use a common code for both cases (one version calls the other) without copying data? For example a kind of iterator "converting" underlying pair to the first or the second value. Maybe something acting the opposite way. Is it possible in C++17? Is it possible more recent standard?

Comment: [`boost::zip_iterator`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html) to go from two loose iterators to an iterator over pairs. [`boost::transform_iterator`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html) for going the other way.